# vim syntax highlighting is messed up after non-standard delimiters in Perl's s///

Tags: perl, vim, syntax-highlighting

When I have something like `s#hello#bye#;` in my Perl script vim's syntax highlighting is messed up after that line. It only works correctly if I use `/` as the delimiter, as in `s/hello/bye/;`. Does anyone know if/how I can fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Debian packaged vim 7.1 highlights OK with s#foo#bar#g. The Debian package does not contain vim's perl-specific features.

Also, no problem with RHEL vim 7.0 which has perl features enabled.

I remember seeing this problem with syntax highlighing some time back, so it might be your vim version and/or perl syntax highlighting rules.

Comment: Specifically, recent support files at https://github.com/petdance/vim-perl or simply [upgrade to Vim 7.3](http://perlbuzz.com/2010/08/vim-73-supports-perl-6.html).

Answer (score 0):

"The only thing that can parse Perl is perl."

But seriously, Perl has a massively irregular grammar and it's not surprising that it confuses some syntax highlighters. The most successful one I've seen is CPerl mode for Emacs. But I guess that's not particularly useful for a Vim user.